# Адаптация карты под мобильные устройства в браузере

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Яндексил, гуглил, не нашёл простого способа, вопрос как делать, какой подход?

Есть cian.ru - там для мобильных создаются кастомные контролы, а в скриптах на них вызывается зум с +1/-1, потом отдельно позиционируются - ну уж очень сложно

Есть https://yandex.ru/pogoda/ - как сделано, не разобрался, но выглядит так как надо)

Нужно, чтобы были контролы + и - справа под палец, кнопка геопозиции, неужели нет готового параметра в API, который такое сделает, без создания кастомных контолов?

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: У Яндекса есть модуль с круглыми контролами: https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-round-controls